# How to set up routing for a php api script create.php?

Tags: php, laravel, rest, routes

I'm trying to setup an url in my laravel project from which my database can receive `post` requests, i have this script i made in `php` and i put in `/public` folder, it works fine when hosted in xampp but when i put it in my laravel project i get a not found error
this is what my `php` script looks like

[image]

api-receive-alert is under `/public` in my laravel project

this is the routing for it in **web.php**

```
Route::post('/receivealert', 'api-receive-alert/api/historique/create.php');
```

Comment: You could try to middleware it to your external script (which runs anywhere but in laravel context - make sure its added to the autoloader tho or require the classes yourself. See docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware#assigning-middleware-to-routes

Answer (score 0):

You need to refactor you code. You cant move an existing project into a laravel instance and its working directly.

But when your code is in the public directory, you don't need to create an route for this. But its better to move this code to laravel.

Comment: it's more of an assignment because it's "easy" to do in Laravel